# Block implicit location mapping loading in Jena

Tags: rdf, jena

What would be a good and simple way to block implicit location mapping loading in Jena?

In other words, if there are files with the following patterns found:

```
"file:location-mapping.rdf;file:location-mapping.n3;file:location-mapping.ttl;"+
        "file:etc/location-mapping.rdf;file:etc/location-mapping.n3;"+
        "file:etc/location-mapping.ttl" ;
```

I want them to be ignored and not automatically loaded.

Comment: What problem does this cause for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `LocationMapper.setGlobalLocationMapper` before any Jena operation is invoked (specifically, before `JenaSystem.init` happens, and that happens via class statics on all API ways into Jena).

Example:

```
        LocationMapper lm = new LocationMapper();
        LocationMapper.setGlobalLocationMapper(lm);
        JenaSystem.init();
```